# Python For loop seems to be getting skipped over

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, skip

This is my first question, so please be nice.
I am leaning Python through an online course.  I completed this assignment using Trinket, and it worked there.  I submitted the code via the online grading system, and it passed there too.  So, I already have been given 'credit' for this assignment.

When I try it in Idle or PyCharm, the code does not work.  It seems to be skipping over the for loop completely.

I have looked at other answers on this type of question, but I cannot figure out how to apply them to my situation.  Please help me understand why my for loop seems to be getting skipped.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname + ".txt")
x = fh.read()
count = 0
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    word = line.split()
    if len(word) == 0:
        continue
    if word[0] != "From":
        continue
    else:
        print(word[1])
        count += 1
print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

In the .txt file being used, there are 27 email addresses that print out one by one, then the final line gives the total count.  Like I said, it works in Trinket and the online code grader, but not in PyCharm or Idle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete the line `x = fh.read()` as a start. That exhausts the file iterator. You also do not need to split the line into words. Just do `if line.lstrip().startswith("From")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `x = fh.read()`, you are reading the content of file and storing it in variable `x`.

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some
>   quantity of data and returns it as a string. size is an optional
>   numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire
>   contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if
>   the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at
>   most size bytes are read and returned. If the end of the file has been
>   reached, f.read() will return an empty string ("").

So, once the file is read completely, `fh` is already at the end of file and iterating it with `for` loop is not yielding any new lines. You have two options here:

1. Change `for line in fh:` with `for line in x:` OR
2. Remove `x = fh.read()`

Comment: Thank you.  Were exactly right.  Simply removing x = fh.read() solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing

```
for line in fh:
```

with

```
for line in x:
```

or removing `x = fh.read()` since it'll read the entire file and left you with an empty file for the loop